# VBScript - Parse Json Value & store as Variable

Tags: json, parsing, vbscript

Ok guys so I need to obtain a value from a JSON file to be used inside a VBScript.

Here is the sample content:

```
{
"installedPacks": {
"vanilla": {
  "name": "vanilla",
  "build": "1.7.10",
  "directory": "%MODPACKS%\\vanilla"
}
```

I would like to read the contents of the file and locate specifically the build value (which in this case is 1.7.10) and assign it to a variable for later use.

I have an existing AppData variable that translates to:

```
objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%") & "\"
```

The file I need to open is in location: AppData & ".technic\installedPacks"

Comment: How are you getting the json?

Comment: Sorry I managed to figure it out. I just used a script to open the file and matched with regexp. I will edit in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I used.

```
Function ForgeJSON(strTxt)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( AppData & "ModPacker\ForgeVer.json", 1)
installedPacks = objFile.ReadAll

Dim oRE
Dim colMatches
Dim oMatch, I
Set oRE = New Regexp
oRE.Global = True
oRE.Pattern = """build"":\s""(.+?)"""
oRE.IgnoreCase = False
Set colMatches = oRE.Execute(strTxt)
For Each oMatch In colMatches

    If oMatch.SubMatches(0) = "recommended" Then
    Else
        strNextmap = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
    End If

Next

If strNextmap = "" Or IsNull (strNextmap) Then
ParseJSON = "No Match Found"
Else
ParseJSON = strNextmap
End If
End Function
```